# How to override the ntp information sent by dhcp in debian?

Tags: debian, ntpd

I have a server in a network receiving all its network information from `DHCP`.  The problem is that the `ntp-server` being sent is not set to UTC.  I want to use the configuration for `ntp` found in `/etc/ntp.conf` but the `DHCP` information takes precedence.  How can I force `ntpd` to use the configuration in `/etc/ntp.conf` as opposed to the one sent by `DHCP`?  What is the `Debian` way to do this?

Comment: What ntp daemon are you using?  What is the current contents of your ntp.conf?  Is the ntpdate package installed?  What DHCP client are you using?  What version of Debian?

Comment: 1. Sever on DHCP 2. NTP server is not "set" to UTC o_O

Comment: Debian squeeze, default ntp.conf (the one that comes after aptitude install ntp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you edit/create /etc/dhclient.conf and uncomment the line "request" with something like this:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, routers, domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
```

Especially, if "ntp-servers" is present, remove it. Under some distribution ( aka Fedora ) it is sent by default, so you have to put this line explicitely so that the default is overriden.

Check `man dhclient.conf` for extended informations.

Comment: This worked perfectly... is there something that one can do in debian that goes more along the lines of /etc/default...

Comment: Regrettably this doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. `dhclient` creates its override configuration even though `ntp-servers` is removed from the `request` line in `/etc/dhclient.conf`.

Answer (score 17):

Not directly answering the question but that may come in handy.

## DHCP behavior

On Debian (at least) the DHCP client is overriding the existing ntp service configuration.

It is controlled by the script `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ntp`:

```
[contents from: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ntp]
NTP_CONF=/etc/ntp.conf
NTP_DHCP_CONF=/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp
...
[hundreds of lines of scripts]
```

The DHCP client receive ntp servers from the DHCP server, it grabs the current ntp service configuration from NTP_CONF path and alters it to include ntp servers received over dhcp, it generates a new ntp configuration file into NTP_DHCP_CONF path, and finally it forces the ntp service to use this new configuration file.

**This results in always using the ntp servers advertised over dhcp.** Bypassing system configuration.

This is hard to debug if not known because the service configuration in '/etc/ntp.conf' is left untouched and is correct on visual inspection. However it is actually ignored and overridden stealthy.

**You can use 'ntpq -pn' to debug what ntp servers are actually being used by the deamon.**

## Mixing DHCP ntp options and system specific configuration

**If there IS a ntp server in your network being advertised by DHCP and you want to ignore it**:

You will need to reconfigure the dhcp client in `/etc/dhclient.conf` to skip the `ntp-servers` dhcp option. Refer to the answer from @Oliver.

Then you can customize the system configuration in `/etc/ntp.conf`

**If there WAS a ntp server advertised by DHCP at some point but not anymore**:

The system ntp configuration might still be overridden by the dhcp client, forcing obsolete ntp servers advertised a long time ago. This dhcp overriding can survive for days, across `ntp service restart` and `reboot`.

To put an end to it, you will need to remove `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp` and restart the ntp service on all your servers.

## Final Word

This is all undocumented, unexpected and hard to debug behavior. That caused me quite the headache today which is why I am documenting this in here.

Comment: For the records, that file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ntp` is part of the `ntp` package. So it is the `ntp` package that tweaks the dhcp client into overriding its own (ntp's) config if an ntp server is provided via dhcp. Then the startscript `/etc/init.d/ntp` has some magic to pick up the config from `/run/ntp.conf.dhcp`

Answer (score 7):

You can also just remove this file: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ntp`, instead of editing your DHCP-requests. This file creates `ntp.conf.dhcp`.

In case `ntp.conf.dhcp` got created at a previous boot, be sure to remove it as well.